# Figure out which middleware causes dangling request in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

From time to time - usually after about several weeks of running - my whole express application becomes unresponsive. No request to it will ever receive a response.

It is clear that the application got stuck in one of my own or one of the vendor middleware, because one of them either does not handle a certain case and as of that neither calles `next()` or some kind of `send()` or probably one of their callbacks is never called.

The problem is that it seems nearly impossible to figure out where the express application is hanging.

For now I created this solution that overwrites the `Layer.prototype.handle_request` of express.js to save the last called handle with the request object:

```
var express = require('express');
var Layer = require('express/lib/router/layer');

// overwrite the default 'handle_request' with a custom one
Layer.prototype.handle_request_org = Layer.prototype.handle_request;

Layer.prototype.handle_request = function(req, res, next) {
  var fn = this.handle;
  req._lastHandleFunction = fn; // store the last called handler in the request object
  return this.handle_request_org.apply(this, arguments);
}

var app = express();

// register a middleware right at the beginning that will show 
// the last 'handle' used by express for that request
//  and the active handles of node.js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  var timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(req._lastHandleFunction);
    console.dir(process._getActiveHandles())
  }, 1000);

  res.on('finish', () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    console.log('finished')
  });

  next();
});
```

Is there an other way to track down such dangling requests.

Comment: You could turn on [debug logging](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html) in Express, but that could generate a massive amount of data over the course of a few weeks.

Comment: @robertklep I also thought about that, the number of data would not be a problem because I could use a limited queue of entires and store it in redis or something like that.  But I couldn't figure out how to determine the middleware that was hanging, only the requests that where not handled.  I would guess it is some `use` middleware that got stuck, and I cannot figure out this middleware in the debug log or do I miss something in the debug logging, that would make this possible.

Comment: Most middleware shows up if you enable debugging for `express:router`. However, it only works if middleware functions are named, otherwise they are being logged as `<anonymous>`, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Also: given that it may take weeks before the issue appears, you should rule out external causes, like databases being restarted and your app not autoreconnecting, and stuff like that. If you're using db drivers that provide events for (connection) errors, make sure you have handlers for those in place.

Comment: @robertklep I also thought about that, but shutting down the db server doing a call and then restarting it didn't cause the same issues. Which does not mean that might not be the reason, but makes it more complicate to figure out. I'll try a combination of both my idea and the debug log. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.